# How to convert these 4 functions in one?

Tags: c#, c#-2.0, factory-pattern

You can use the enum: `enum StatusRouter { Stop = 0, Start, Resume, Suspect };`

```
public bool StartSelectedRouter()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m_listPlatforms.Count; i++)
    {
        if (m_listPlatforms[i].IsCheked)
            m_listPlatforms[i].Start();
    }
    return false;
}
public bool ResumeSelectedRouter()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m_listPlatforms.Count; i++)
    {
        if (m_listPlatforms[i].IsCheked)
            m_listPlatforms[i].Resume();
    }
    return false;
}
public bool SuspendSelectedRouter()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m_listPlatforms.Count; i++)
    {
        if (m_listPlatforms[i].IsCheked)
            m_listPlatforms[i].Suspend();
    }
    return false;
}
public bool StopSelectedRouter()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m_listPlatforms.Count; i++)
    {
        if (m_listPlatforms[i].IsCheked)
            m_listPlatforms[i].Stop();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: How to convert these 4 functions in one?

Comment: BTW, I suspect that "Suspect" actually should be "Suspend"

Comment: @digEmAll, yes yes thanks. @Uwe Keim, No this not homework.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass in a lambda defining the Action you want to do on each element.

Something like:

```
public bool ChangeSelectedRouterState(Action<Router> action) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m_listPlatforms.Count; i++)
    {
        if (m_listPlatforms[i].IsCheked)
            action(m_listPlatforms[i]);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Call like this:

```
ChangeSelectedRouterState(r => r.Stop());
```

You will need to substitute the type `Router`, which I invented for my answer, for your specific type you are working on.

Comment: Where did he use Linq in his answer?

Comment: @Jan, sorry, I don't understand that comment ? The question did not state anything about using LINQ or not, nor is my answer using LINQ.

Comment: There was a comment on your answer, something like 'I can't use Linq for this project'. Apparently it has been removed later on.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the strategy pattern by passing in a Action to a method that performs the required action (assuming your class is called Platform) - so something like this:

```
    public bool ActionSelectedRouter(Action<Platform> action)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < m_listPlatforms.Count; i++)
        {
            if (m_listPlatforms[i].IsCheked)
                action(m_listPlatforms[i]);
        }
        return false;            
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You extract the repeating part, the loop, and pass the action you want to do:

```
public bool DoSelectedRouter(StatusRouter statusRouter)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m_listPlatforms.Count; i++)
    {
        if (m_listPlatforms[i].IsCheked)
        {
            switch(statusRouter)
            {
               case StatusRouter.Stop:
                 m_listPlatforms[i].Stop();
                 break;
               case StatusRouter.Resume:
                 m_listPlatforms[i].Resume();
                 break;       
                 .......
            }
        }            
    }
    return false;
}
```

Of course, you can always discard the enum and pass a function delegate of action you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy DoAction into the function, but this is more readable

```
public bool DoActionSelectedRouter(StatusRouter action)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m_listPlatforms.Count; i++)
    {
        if (m_listPlatforms[i].IsCheked)
        {
            DoAction(m_listPlatforms[i], action);
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private void DoAction(Platform platform,StatusRouter  action)
{
     switch(action){
         case(StatusRouter.Stop):
         {
                platform.Stop();
                break;
         }
         case(StatusRouter.Start):
         {
                platform.Start();
                break;
         }
         case(StatusRouter.Suspend):
         {
                platform.Suspend();
                break;
         }
         case(StatusRouter.Resume):
         {
                platform.Resume();
                break;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This is the answer closest to what I'd do.

Comment: @peer: break is not a function, so no round brackets ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
Public bool StartRouterAction(StatusRouter Action)
{

switch(Action)
{
    case StatusRouter.Start:

// your start action

break; 

  case StatusRouter.Resume:

// your Resume action

  break; 

  case StatusRouter.Suspend:

  // your suspend action

       break; 


case StatusRouter.Stop:

 // your stop action

 break; 

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First I'd factor out the status setting of a single router into a separate function. I'd make this function a member on the `Router` class.

Then I'd write a helper function getting me all checked routers. And finally a function that calls the `SetRouterStatus` function on each of them.

This way every function has a single responsibility and can be reused.

A few other issues with your code:
`Cheked` should be `Checked` and `Suspect` should the `Suspend`.

Why do your functions return a `bool` that's always false?

```
public void SetSelectedRoutersStatus(StatusRouter status)
{
    foreach(var router in GetCheckedRouters())
    {
        SetRouterStatus(router);
    }
}

IEnumerable<Router> GetCheckedRouters()
{
    return m_listPlatforms.Where(router=>router.Checked);
}

void SetRouterStatus(Router router,StatusRouter status)
{
     switch(status)
     {
         case(StatusRouter.Stop):
         {
                router.Stop();
                break;
         }
         case(StatusRouter.Start):
         {
                router.Start();
                break;
         }
         case(StatusRouter.Suspend):
         {
                router.Suspend();
                break;
         }
         case(StatusRouter.Resume):
         {
                router.Resume();
                break;
         }
         default:
           throw new NotSupportedException("Invalid StatusRouter");
     }
}
```

(based on @peer's answer)